# Width 100% does not fill the screen

Tags: html, css

I was browsing the other related threads but i couldnt find a fix..
The Div does not fill 100% of the screen with the chosen background color, only the width of the `<li>`
CSS:

```
#menuspace{
    background: #2175bc;padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;
}
#menubutton {
margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
}

#menubutton li {
    display: inline;
}

#menubutton li a {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #2175bc;
    color: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menuspace">
<ul id="menubutton">
<li><a href="http://www.example.net/">Home</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: What contains the `menuspace` `div`?

Comment: What effect specifically are you trying to create?  I'm quite confused.  Just a menu DIV with a set of buttons inside?  Why is a <ul> useful here?

Comment: Its a menu... i just left out the remaining 7 <li> tags to not waste space in this post.

Comment: DIV is a block element & it's take auto of the element so there is no need to define width:100% to it

Comment: See my answer and let me know if any thing i am lagging so i can make the changes as per your requirement.

Comment: if any other issues in your code and if you think i can help i m here to help you ask me if you want. thanks for selecting my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the 'float: left' on the #menubutton li a. Remove that and the div will go 100% of the screen. The float makes the parent div menuspaces think that there's really no content contained in it (the div is actually going 100% but has no height). You could also leave the float in there and simply add some content:

```
<div id="menuspace">
<ul id="menubutton">
<li><a href="http://www.example.net/">Home</a></li>
</ul>Look the div goes to 100% now</div>
```

Comment: Ah dont work, just messes the li items all over the place, But overflow:hidden works except now other div's are pulled over it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle -

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/embedded/result/

Note: I have added hover on `<a>` tag so it look better.

Comment: Thank you kind expert. I appreciate it, works fine now, had to fix some other contents that was pulled over it, but needed to be done anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There is a float in your `#menubutton li a` so you have to clear is his parent which is `#menubutton`. So, write like this:

```
#menubutton{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css for menuspace to this:

```
#menuspace{ 
    background: #2175bc;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:auto;
}
```

The reason why you are having this issue is because of the float:left on the li tag. overflow:auto on parent element will clear floats (or you can add an empty div right after ul and set style to clear:both on it).

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to fix this.

1. Float `#menuspace` as well. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5JFE/))
2. Add an empty div after the `ul` with `float: none; clear: both` applied. ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5JFE/1/))

There are probably more ways to accomplish what you're after (as suggested above by others).

Comment: No success. I give up, i'll just copy&paste a menu from somewhere, i hate css.

Comment: What browser are you having the problems with? Or is the solution (that works in the fiddles) not working in your code? If it's the latter, we'll need to see more of your code in order to figure out why the solutions we've posted thus far are not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

see this

http://jsfiddle.net/U5JFE/2/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you don't need to give width and all it will take automatically the width for deep details check it my example its simple :

http://jsfiddle.net/U5JFE/7/